# Variable not being updated in function -

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
  const [isValid, setisValid] = useState(false);

    const GetData = () => {
        debugger;
        if (type.isValid === "true") {
            setisValid (true);
        }
        else {
            setisValid(false);
        }

        GetMyData(ID, isValid)
            .then((response) => {
                if (componentMounted.current) {
                    const apiResult: ApiResult<ItemApproval> = response.data;
                    if (!apiResult?.success && apiResult?.message) {
                        onError("Checking validity", apiResult?.message ?? "Error retrieving state value");
                    }
                    setData(apiResult.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error: any) {
                console.log("Error in GetData: ", error);
                if (componentMounted.current) {
                    onError("Error", "Error retrieving state");
                }
            });
    };
```

I have the above code, when i debug and inspect variables, isValid is true and `setisValid (true);` is being executed but isValid is false on line  `GetMyData(ID, isValid)`, why isn't my updated value being piacked?

Comment: `setIsValid` won't update the variable value *now*. It just means the next time you get it from `const [isValid, setisValid] = useState(false);`  it's going to be the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

So when you call a function it will take a snapshot( not in literal sense ) of you app's/components's current State.

therefor, even if you change your state it will only update in after the function which you invoked finishes

This is a problem many react developers face

what works best for me is to use a `ref` variable instead ( make sure that you do not depend on this ref's value to make state changes )

you can do something like this

```
const isValidref = useRef(false);

const GetData = () => {
  debugger;
  if (type.isValid === "true") {
    isValidref.current = true;
  }
  else {
    isValidref.current = false;
  }

  GetMyData(ID, isValidref.current)
      .then((response) => {
          if (componentMounted.current) {
              const apiResult: ApiResult<ItemApproval> = response.data;
              if (!apiResult?.success && apiResult?.message) {
                  onError("Checking validity", apiResult?.message ?? "Error retrieving state value");
              }
              setData(apiResult.data);
          }
      })
      .catch(function (error: any) {
          console.log("Error in GetData: ", error);
          if (componentMounted.current) {
              onError("Error", "Error retrieving state");
          }
      });
};
```

PS: Here is a link to a blog which help me understand a little bit more about how react works and address this type of issue - https://www.developerway.com/posts/fantastic-closures

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to have a state here while you can pass `type.isValid === "true"` this at the place of isValid.

one other thing you are facing the issue is because thats how react's state setter functions work. These works like a Async functions so when you try to run this function your `GetMyData` function completes its execution while your `setIsValid` is still in the execution phase.

To over come this use `GetData` function to only set the state. And have a `useEffect` in place with a dependency array of `[isValid]` and place your `GetMyData` function in there.

Answer (score 0):

useState doesn't update state immediately, so in GetMyData **isValid** in not updated. you can use **type.isValid === "true"** as its second parameter.

```
const [isValid, setisValid] = useState(false);

const GetData = () => {
    debugger;
    if (type.isValid === "true") {
        setisValid (true);
    }
    else {
        setisValid(false);
    }

    GetMyData(ID, type.isValid === "true")
        .then((response) => {
            if (componentMounted.current) {
                const apiResult: ApiResult<ItemApproval> = response.data;
                if (!apiResult?.success && apiResult?.message) {
                    onError("Checking validity", apiResult?.message ?? "Error retrieving state value");
                }
                setData(apiResult.data);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error: any) {
            console.log("Error in GetData: ", error);
            if (componentMounted.current) {
                onError("Error", "Error retrieving state");
            }
        });
};
```